# Receive a JSON input from [FormBody] and bind it in c# model

Tags: c#, json, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

Im using .net core 7
I wan to do very basic thing but my binding class is empty.

```
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
        [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
        [Route(nameof(UploadSalesInvoice))]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadSalesInvoice([FromBody] InvoiceDto content
            , [FromQuery]string requestId = "007", long apiKeyId = 1, [FromQuery]string sendToCir = "Auto"){...}
```

My binding model:

```
    public class InvoiceDto
    {
        [JsonProperty("buyer")]
        public Buyer? Buyer { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// BG-7: Buyer
    /// </summary>
    public class Buyer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// BT-48: Buyer vat
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty("buyer_vat")]
        public string? BuyerVat { get; set; }
    }
```

When I run the program, it goes into this webApi method above but my binding object is empty.
Im using swagger, and in the box for content I put:

```
{"buyer":{"buyer_vat":"something"}}
```

Is there any better approach?

Comment: Can you show your startup? What serializer do you use?

Comment: I test your code, but I can get the binding object, see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpWvb.gif) . I use asp.net core 7 web api temple, maybe you can try again. Besides, I have  `<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.2" />`

Answer (score -1):

By default ASP.NET in .NET Core 7 is going to be set up to use System.Text for serialization.  `JsonProperty` is a Newtonsoft.Json attribute.  Try using `JsonPropertyName` instead or alter your serializer to use Newtonsoft.Json.